# Web2py Email Authentication

Tags: web2py

I Have set Web2py to send email verification on registration and not to allow log on until verified with the following settings:

```
mail=auth.settings.mailer 

mail.settings.server = 'smtp.gmail.com:587' 
mail.settings.sender = 'my_email_address@gmail.com' 
mail.settings.tls=True
mail.settings.login = 'my_email_address@gmail.com:my_gmail_password'


auth.settings.registration_requires_verification = True
auth.settings.registration_requires_approval = False
auth.settings.login_after_registration = False
```

Email is being sent for password reset but not for registration. It also is allowing logon.

i am not sure why?

Here is my register form code:

```
def register():

    form = SQLFORM(db.auth_user)
    form.element('table').insert(-1,(T('Please confirm that you are not a machine :'),Recaptcha(request, PUBLIC_KEY, PRIVATE_KEY, options="theme:'white'"),''))
    if form.process(onvalidation=lola).accepted:
        session.flash = 'record inserted'
        make_thumb(db.auth_user, form.vars.id,(250,250))
        redirect(URL('login'))
    return dict(form=form)
```

Comment: When you register, you should get a flash message saying the verification email was sent or that there was an error sending it -- do you get either of those messages?

Comment: No i don't see "Verification email was sent".
The only response message is "Record inserted"

Comment: Sounds like you're not using the auth.register() function but simply presenting users with a standard form based on the auth_user table. Can you show the code you are using to let users register?

Comment: That's correct. I have added my register controller above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want some of the extra registration features, such as email verification, you'll need to use the built-in `auth.register()` function:

```
def register():
    return dict(form=auth.register())
```

If you need to run callback functions on validation and on form acceptance, you can specify them using `auth.settings.register_onvalidation` and `auth.settings.register_onaccept`.

Comment: This works.
i had it make a thumbnail of the profile image on accept. when i try
auth.settings.register_onaccept =[make_thumb(db.auth_user, form.vars.id,(250,250))]

it doesn't like the undeclared variables. is there a way around it or is it a trade off for the email verification?

Comment: `register_onaccept` (and `register_onvalidation`) should not be an actual function call -- instead, it should be a function (or other callable object, such as a lambda). It should take a single argument, which is the registration form object. In this case, you could do something like: `auth.settings.register_onaccept = lambda form: make_thumb(db.auth_user, form.vars.id, (250, 250))`.